# Modify existing XML data with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

Sample data:

```xml
<lieu>
  <l_nr>
  </l_nr>
  <strasse>gasse</strasse>
  <h_nr>0</h_nr>
  <f_name>0</f_name>
  <v_name>0</v_name>
  <txt>1 Knoflach Josef</txt>
</lieu>
```

I would like to change the "line number" item `<l_nr>`, by adding 1 to 6000.

And also split the `<txt>` item:

```bsh
$path = "lieu.xml"
$fiche = New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $path

$rue = $xml.lieu.txt[0].Split(" ")
$rue[0]
$rue[1]
$rue[2]

$xml | % {$_ -replace ($_.h_nr,$n_st[0],$_.f_name=$n_st[1],$_.v_name=$n_st[2])}
(1..$xml.lieu.txt.count) | % {$_ -replace $_.l_nr}

$xml.Save($path)
```

It's throwing the following error:

```
Indexation impossible dans un tableau Null.
Au caractère Ligne:16 : 51
+ ... $_ -replace ($_.h_nr,$n_st[0],$_.f_name=$n_st[1],$_.v_name=$n_st[2])}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post and add the code you wrote for processing the xml. This will help us figure out what is wrong. Thank you :)

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-3.0#replacement-operator). The `-replace` operator doesn't work the way you seem to expect.

Answer (score 0):

use `=` to set the value rather than `-replace`

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\dave\Temp\file.xml

$Split = $xml.lieu.txt -split "\s"

$xml.lieu.h_nr   = $Split[0]
$xml.lieu.f_name = $split[1]
$xml.lieu.v_name = $Split[2]
```

Comment: Hello Sir, thank for your reply, bat i have it! How You replace $split[0] now to the item "h_nr"? foreatch?

Comment: @arenas what are you looping through? Can you update your example to show what you have and what you want?

Comment: Hello Dave, I m so sorry for you your idee is not work: Look "$Split = $xml.lieu.txt[0].Split(" ")
$Split[0]
$split[1]
$Split[2]

"n rue"
$xml.lieu.h_nr   -replace $Split[0]
$xml.lieu.f_name -replace $Split[1]
$xml.lieu.v_name -replace $Split[2]"

Comment: I've updated my answer. it's splinting by `"\s"` now. You are still using `-replace`?

Comment: Dave: Yes: add also "-ToString()"

Comment: Dave , I stop all and i have to investigat of this probleme. Thanks

Comment: Dave, I m back. Thank @r